# How to append character at the end of every url : asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url, web-config

**Introduction**
I am working on an existing website.  [Here](http://fatehjangcity.com),
I am using google adsense for my website as most people do, the problem i faced that the ads were not working for the website.

Lately, i have found that if i append '/' at the end of each url, then ads starts displaying.

**Problem**
Now, i been looking for help to append the '/' char to every url of my webpage but (search results)either not working or relative.

For example : if i have webpage http://example.com, and i need it to http://example.com/

**Handlers in web.config(i don't this this will be needed, anyways)**

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
  <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
  <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
  <remove name="ScriptResource" />
  <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

  <remove name="ChartImage_axd"/>
  <add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd"/>
  <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx"/>
  <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <remove name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx"/>
  <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd"/>
  <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
</handlers>
```

I dont know how to write code for web.config file or route file, if someone knew the way, please help.

Thanks for your time.